# iOS 11.2 imageFile

Tags: ios, xcode

my device is currently using iOS 11.2.1 but I like to use Xcode8. Does anyone know where I can find the 11.2 image file so I can install projects on my device? I'm trying to get the imageFile without downloading Xcode9. I can't seem to find it on the Apple website

Comment: Just use Xcode 9. Simple solution since you need to Xcode 9 to get the files needed to make Xcode 8 work with iOS 11 devices.

Comment: I know, I had 9 before but I reverted back to 8 because 9 was too slow on my machine

Answer (score 0):

You can download them here: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Under Release Software, expand iOS 11.2.1, and download the image of your device.